# Grails 3 unable to resolve class oracle.sql

Tags: oracle, grails, jdbc, grails3

Trying to run a grails 3 application with `jdbc6` dependency. I'm trying to import the below libraries in my groovy service that is supposed to connect to an Oracle database to call a stored procedure.

```
import oracle.sql.ARRAY
import oracle.sql.ArrayDescriptor
import oracle.jdbc.OracleCallableStatement
import java.sql.Connection
import groovy.sql.Sql

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormatter
import com.wwt.itemuploadapi.rectypes.Rectype

import java.sql.SQLException

class ExcelService {

def dataSource

private static final FILE_HEADERS = [
        'First Name': 'firstName',
        'Last Name': 'lastName'
]

def callApi(List<Rectype> rectype) {

    OracleCallableStatement callableStmt = null

    try {
        def conn = dataSource.getConnection()
        ArrayDescriptor descriptor = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor("TBLTYPE", conn.unwrap(oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection.class))
        ARRAY dataElementsArray = new ARRAY(descriptor, conn.unwrap(oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection.class), (Object[])rectype.toArray())
        Map map = conn.getTypeMap()
        map.put("REC_TYPE", Rectype.class)
        callableStmt = (OracleCallableStatement)conn.prepareCall("{call package.procedure_name(?)}")
        callableStmt.setArray(1, dataElementsArray);

        callableStmt.execute()
    }
    catch (SQLException ex) {
        println(ex)
    }
}
```

I get the below three errors upon starting up. But I have these classes under my `Gradle: com.oracle:ojdbc6:11.2.0.3` library. So I'm not sure why it can't recognize them.

```
 `unable to resolve class oracle.sql.ARRAY`
 `unable to resolve class oracle.sql.ArrayDescriptor`
 `unable to resolve class oracle.jdbc.OracleCallableStatement`
```

Any suggestions why these classes can't be found?

Answer (score 0):

```
oracle.jdbc.OracleCallableStatement
```

is not the correct class to use anymore for the ojdbc dependency version you are using.

That should be updated to this import and class:

```
import java.sql.CallableStatement
CallableStatement callableStmt = null
```

Here is a link which will show you what you need to do to replace the other deprecated classes (`oracle.sql.ARRAY` and `oracle.sql.ArrayDescriptor`) you are trying to use:
https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JAJDB/deprecated-list.html#class